# Default ggplot font on macos

Tags: r, macos, ggplot2, fonts

I've searched a lot but I was unable to find a way to detect what is the default font used by ggplot theme_classic() on **MacOS** . Is there a way to know what font I'm currently using when plotting with ggplot2 ?

Comment: The default font family `""` is "sans" which on a Mac is Helvetica. Try `systemfonts::match_font("")`.

Comment: By default, ggplot will not specify a font family, including when you use `theme_classic`. Even if you build the plot into a grob table, you will see that the individual graphic objects have their fontfamily set to `""`, which means that the plotting device will use its own default font. This varies according to the graphics device you are drawing with. For example, the pdf device defaults to Helvetica

Comment: Thanks to stefan and to Allan Cameron for the complete answer.